# Sometimes wait for Coroutine to complete in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, asynchronous, async-await

I'm working on a system to save game state in Unity.  The current structure looks like this:

```
public void SaveGame() {
    StopAllCoroutines();
    if (source != null)
    {
        source.Cancel();
    }
    StartCoroutine(DoSave());
}

protected IEnumerator DoSave(){
    /// Code that prepares a bunch of stuff necessary to save the game goes here
    foreach (item in itemsToSave)
    {
        // Code that adds 'item' to a data structure in memory that is accessible by later functions goes here //
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.05f);
    }
    
    source = new CancellationTokenSource();   
    WriteFiles(source.Token);
}

private async Task WriteFiles(CancellationToken token)
{
    Task task = Task.Run(() => GenerateSaveFiles(), token);
    // (A canceled task will raise an exception when awaited).
    await task;
}

private void GenerateSaveFiles()
{
    /// Functions that actually write to disk go here 
    /// E.g. File.WriteAllText();
    /// This function has access to the place in memory where 'items' were being added to in the DoSave() foreach loop, so it just dumps that memory storage to disk
}
```

I set it up this way so I can save asynchronously in a separate thread and track the status of it (e.g. if it fails or not, and error messages).

`SaveGame()` is then called around my code base whenever different events (like picking up items, killing enemies etc) to save the game in real-time. This mostly works well for 99% of my use-cases but there are instances where I want to call `SavGame()` and wait for it to finish before doing anything else at all.  For example, if a player dies, I want to write the state to disk without giving a chance for anything else (e.g. respawning the player in a different scene) to occur.

I have looked into a few things like callbacks (e.g. https://codesaying.com/action-callback-in-unity/) but I'm not sure how to correctly set this up for my use-case of mostly having `SaveGame()` tasks run async but other times being able to wait for it to complete, or at a minimum having the method that called `SaveGame()` knowing when it has completed.

Comment: Can you pass the "item" object as a argument to WriteFiles instead of using fields on the class to get the data? That way if the data changes while the thread is running it still will read the copy that was passed in as a argument and you dont need to wait for the save to finish to respawn the player.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this comment in its relation to my question.  I'm not worried that data will change, instead I'm worried that the data won't get written in time.  For example loading the next scene tries to read the save file so it knows how to configure some stuff in the scene, but if the save file isn't fully written this will probably fail.  I could probably have two different ways to read the data (one from file, one from memory) based on why the scene was loaded, but that seems annoying.

Comment: Ah, you did not make it clear the new scene would call a LoadGame function. Why not always load from memory, when you do a real load just have the load copy the value in to memory then do the normal load from memory code.

Comment: Because TLDR I'm not sure how to do that in an easy way with the saving system I'm using.  E.g. if i read directly from file with the functions it provides it is super easy to load stuff directly into game objects, but if i just read the raw values myself into memory I have to do a bunch of extra work putting those values in the right place.  Seems like it would be easier to just hold up unity until saving is complete since it takes such a small amount of time.

Comment: Thinking more about it, even if I solved for an easy way to load from memory, I would still worry that writing to memory would not complete in time.  Even though that's unlikely to happen it seems like I wouldn't have any guarantees.  So my initial thought about loading from memory would still require me to wait for writing to the memory store to complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, after a lot of reading and effort I was able to get this to work.  There's a lot of things that can get in the way because of my setup of using Coroutine but also a Task and other Coroutines nested within.

My solution was two-fold

1. For the Coroutine (`DoSave()`) and any other Coroutines nested within I pass a parameter `waitForSaveComplete` and if true, I do not run any of the yield statements in `DoSave()` or its nested coroutines.  So from the example in my question, I wrapped all my yield statements like so:

```cs
if (!waitForSaveComplete) 
{    
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.05f);
}
```

I also had some synchronized nested Coroutines that whose yield statements I wrapped in the same way.

Next, I changed the calls of nested coroutines from:

```cs
yield return StartCoroutine(MySynchronizedCoroutine());
```

to:

```cs
if(!waitForSaveComplete) {
    yield return StartCoroutine(MySynchronizedCoroutine(waitForSavComplete));
} else 
{ 
    // IMPORTANT:  Make sure MySynchronizedCoroutine also uses 
    // waitForSaveComplete to wrap its own yield statements 
    // or else this won't work!!!
    StartCoroutine(MySynchronizedCoroutine(waitForSavComplete));
}
```

Wrapping the yield statements like this works because that's where the Coroutine pauses and gives up control until the corresponding `Wait` condition is met.  Up until that point it is 'blocking' and given that I'm not sure why it took me so long to think of this.

2. For the Task I used a `WaitUntil` in the async case to make sure it completes before anything else happens within the Coroutine itself.  In the `waitForSaveComplete` case I simply did not even start a Task, instead running `GenerateSaveFiles()` directly like so

```cs
if (waitForSaveComplete) 
{
    GenerateSaveFiles();
} else
{
    Task writeTask = WriteFiles(source.Token);
    yield return new WaitUntil(() => writeTask.IsCompleted);
}
```

Again, another 'duh' moment, just don't like.. start a task in cases where it's not needed.

This seems to work but also kind of complicated because of the bit with the nested coroutines which seems like quite the fertile ground for horrific, hard to track bugs.  Alas my async programming experience is severely limited so I don't have any better design or implementation ideas.

Answer (score 1):

Just do a simple Boolean property that anyone can access:

```cs
public bool IsSavingGame { 
    get; private set; 
}

// ...

private IEnumerator SaveGameCoroutine(){
    IsSavingGame = true;

    // Your save functionality.

    IsSavingGame = false;
}
```

For example, if you want deny any loading of scene while it's saving, you can write up this script:

```cs
// or you can singleton it
[SerializeField]
private SaveManager yourSaveManger

public void LoadScene(){
    StartCoroutine(LoadSceneCoroutine());
}

private IEnumerator LoadSceneCoroutine(){
    while (yourSaveManger.IsSavingGame){
        // Show a loading or saving screen or something
        yield return null;
    }

    SceneManager.LoadScene("Your Scene Name");
}
```

Comment: Would this work since the WriteFiles function is running on a thread in a task?  Would the boolean go in the task instead of the coroutine?

Comment: @CHP Yes, this will work. If the variable is not local (function), different tasks/coroutines use the same instances of variable just as everyone else do.

Comment: I put a debug.log both where you suggest and then in the `GenerateSaveFiles()` function and the `GenerateSaveFiles()` one seems to be called later.  Still, this could work if I put it in `GenerateSaveFiles()`.  I'll give it a shot and see if I encounter any odd behavior

Comment: I tested this approach and it works after finding the right place to set the boolean.  I would recommend it for the general case for sure.  In my specific case I decided against it because so many things can trigger a SaveGame() call and in MOST cases I am cancelling earlier calls in favor of late ones with updated data.  I found it difficult to use the boolean method because I would then have had to implement some kind of Save queue if a SaveGame() call I want to be 'blocking' as in the level load case is called before another save call.  Not sure if I explained that well.